# MVC5: Passing method values from View to Conroller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I'm working on an MVC5 project and I'm having some difficulties with passing values from the view into a method on my controller using razor syntax. Here is the code from my View:

```
@{string value = "myValue"};

<a href="@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController", new {Model.UserGuid, value})" id="MyId">Click Here</a>
```

Here is the code from MyController:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(Guid id, string value){

    if(value == "myValue"){

        //do something

    } else {

        //do something different

    }
}
```

When debugging this method, both the Guid and the value are coming through as null. What am I missing? I even trying using an int and that didn't work. Any ideas how I can pass a string from the view to controller and into the MyMethod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new { id = Model.UserGuid, value = value}
```

Comment: That's all I was missing? Wow. So it's good to know that you have assign the values in the view. That worked like a charm.

Comment: @Chris Marisic, With this context, it needs to be "value = value". Please change it back. Just having "value" is wrong.

Comment: @Debo you're mistaken, `new { value = value }` and `new { value }` are exactly the same.

Comment: @Chris Marisic I completely agree with you, however, in this given context, it is incorrect. the first "value" is in reference to the string "myValue" in the view. The second "value" is in reference to the method MyMethod on the controller. With that said, just leaving it at "value" will pass a null value.

Comment: @Debo, Both `new { id = Model.UserGuid, value = value }` and `new { id = Model.UserGuid, value }` should be generating identical `href="/MyController/MyController/####?value=myValue` and the value of the parameter `value` will be `"myValue"` Having said that, the original answer should not have been edited and I have rolled it back